# Can Cycles use multiple UV layers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I'm trying to match Cycles to a Blender-Internal material setup and I didn't see a way for cycles to have an image reference more then one UV map.

Is it possible to have a node setup with 2 image textures, each using a different mesh UVLayer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, the different UVMaps can be selected by an *attribute node* and plugged into the vector input of an *image texture node* as well as into another *image texture node* vector input holding an alpha mask of the image referenced from the first texture node. This way multiple textures (and UVMaps) can be mixed for a single material output.

This technique is demonstrated in [this tutorial](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?245468).

[image: Simple nodes-setup demonstrating the usage of two UV Layouts in a Cycles material.]

Answer (score 19):

## Update

There is [now a dedicate UV map node](https://developer.blender.org/rBcb7cfd3ab6be) (will be [in 2.71](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles#Nodes)).

[image]

---

*Original answer:*

As [already mentioned by stacker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2178/599), this can be achieved with the *[Attribute](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Attribute)* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Add node > Input > Attribute*)

> **Attribute**
> Retrieve attribute attached to the object or mesh. Currently UV maps and vertex color layers can be retrieved this way by their names, with layers and attributes planned to be added. Also internal attributes like P (position), N (normal), Ng (geometric normal) may be accessed this way, although there are more convenient nodes for this.

For example:

[image]

Simply put the name of the UV map in the *Name* parameter, and use the *Vector* output as the UV coordinates.

The UV map with the camera icon selected in *Object data > UV maps* will be used by the *Texture coordinate* node:

[image] [image]

While you can mix *Attribute* nodes with *Texture Coordinate* nodes, I personally find using only *Attribute* nodes is easier with more than one UV map, as the name of the UV map is already on the node.