# Use multiple UV maps in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, uv

I want to define two different UV maps for one object.  One will have the nodes pushed around to match features in an image for dents and scratches, intended to affect the displacement of the material.  The other provides color, a pigmentation pattern, and mapped in a way unrelated to the scratches/dents.

I found how to create multiple UV maps by going into the mesh properties, UV Maps, and click the + button.  I have pushed nodes and am convinced I have two separate UV maps, named ScratchyUV and PigmUV, each arranged on its appropriate image in the UV/Image Editor as I like.

For the material, I have two Texture Coordinate nodes. One feeds an Image Texture for the scratch/dent image, which feeds the Material displacement input.  It actually works!  Yay.   The other Texture Coordinate node goes to a Diffuse Shader and that goes to Material surface.

Where I am stuck: How do I choose which UV map gets used for which Texture Coordinate?  What would make sense to me is the Texture Coordinate having a list or something to choose a UV map.  This is probably all wrong, but I have nothing better than guesses!   What is the trick to choose UV maps in this kind of setup?

I could show a screenshot my nodes setup, but there's a lot of extra stuff for tweaking the details, and it's not as I described.  What I described should be enough for the purpose of the question, though.

Comment: See this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/can-cycles-use-multiple-uv-layers/2178#2178

Comment: Sparing a few minor specifics, this appears to be an exact duplicate of [Can Cycles use multiple UV layers?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2176/12)