# How do you apply a texture to select faces of a mesh

Tags: texturing

I have build a basic house but I would like to use different textures for the roof and walls. Here is what I have now.

[image]

The brick texture is on the roof when i want it to be a different texture

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way if the texture isn't UV-mapped, is to assign each face to separate materials in Edit mode:

[image: 1a]

then assign appropriate texture to each material, as needed. Otherwise if the texture uses UV map, just separate the UV maps for both sections of the object:

[image: 2a]

then paint each sections with the appropriate color (the roof is the top section, in this picture).

Comment: How do you "separete the uv maps for both sections"?

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a separate UV layer in *Object Data > UV maps*:

[image]

## Blender Internal:

Assign a different material to the roof faces, then select the alternate UV map in the material texture settings:

[image]

## Cycles:

In cycles the alternate UV map can be selected in a node setup with the *Attribute node*:

[image]

See [Can Cycles use multiple UV layers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2176/599)

Comment: Can UV maps also be used in attribute nodes? I was only aware of vertex colors.

Comment: @bzal [Yes, they can](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14262/599). However a separate "UV map" node has been added since this answer was written. In most cases you'll probably want to use that instead.