# what can you call from the attribute node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I know you can call density or flame for example from the attribute node. I was wondering what else you can write in the name slot. And maybe a bit of explanation of the attribute node.

[image]

thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: the blender 2.79 manual has a link to this thread

Comment: Even the latest 2.91 documentation has link to this question and its answer :)

Answer (score 56):

Currently you can get:

- `density` When used on a domain object, this is gives a scalar defining the density of any smoke inside the domain. All three outputs are the same.
- `flame` When used on a domain object, this is gives a scalar defining the density of any fire inside the domain. All three outputs are the same.
- `color` When used on a domain object, this is gives the color of the smoke. The color and vector outputs are the same. The fac output is an average of the channels.
- `N` This gives the normals of the object. You can also get this info from the *normal* output of a geometry node.
- `Ng` This gives the true normals of the object. You can also get this info from the *true normal* output of a geometry node.
- `pointiness` This gives a scalar representing the amount of curvature of the object's surface based on it's normals. You can also get this info from the *pointiness* output of the a geometry node.
- `uv` This gives the UV coordinates of the active UV map (the map with the camera icon active). Same as the *UV* output of the *texture coordinate* node.
- `generated` This gives the generated coordinates of the object. Same as the *Generated* output of the *texture coordinate* node.
- `tangent` This gives the tangent coordinates using the object's active UV map. Same as the *Tangent* output of a *tangent* node with *direction* set to *UV map*.
- *name of uv map*
  This allows you to get the UV coordinates stored in a specific UV map belonging to the object with the material. You usually want to use the *vector* output, though the *color* output is the same. The *Fac* output gives an average of the channels.

Note that as of 2.71 there is a dedicated UV map node which makes this obsolete.

- *name of vertex color set*
  This gives the vertex colors stored in the named vertex color datablock. Again the *color* and *vector* outputs are the same, and the *Fac* output is an average.

In the case of a vertex color datablock and a UV map with the same name, the UV map will be used by the attribute node.

---

There are actually quite a few more [in the code](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/render/attribute.cpp;930bf584782da23e7269d794fff19f0d9ca3017b$192), the ones listed above are just the ones which appear to work as of 2.74 `930bf58` (latest master at the time of writing).

For a complete list, see [line `192` of `/intern/cycles/render/attribute.cpp`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/render/attribute.cpp;930bf584782da23e7269d794fff19f0d9ca3017b$192):

<sub>I put `//no output` next to the ones which appeared to do nothing.</sub>

```c++
switch(std) {
    case ATTR_STD_VERTEX_NORMAL:
        return "N";
    case ATTR_STD_FACE_NORMAL:
        return "Ng";
    case ATTR_STD_UV:
        return "uv";
    case ATTR_STD_GENERATED:
        return "generated";
    case ATTR_STD_GENERATED_TRANSFORM:
        return "generated_transform";   //no output
    case ATTR_STD_UV_TANGENT:
        return "tangent";
    case ATTR_STD_UV_TANGENT_SIGN:
        return "tangent_sign";          //no output
    case ATTR_STD_VERTEX_COLOR:
        return "vertex_color";
    case ATTR_STD_POSITION_UNDEFORMED:
        return "undeformed";            //no output
    case ATTR_STD_POSITION_UNDISPLACED:
        return "undisplaced";           //no output
    case ATTR_STD_MOTION_VERTEX_POSITION:
        return "motion_P";              //no output
    case ATTR_STD_MOTION_VERTEX_NORMAL:
        return "motion_N";              //no output
    case ATTR_STD_PARTICLE:
        return "particle";              //no output
    case ATTR_STD_CURVE_INTERCEPT:
        return "curve_intercept";       //no output
    case ATTR_STD_CURVE_RANDOM:
        return "curve_random";
    case ATTR_STD_PTEX_FACE_ID:
        return "ptex_face_id";          //no output
    case ATTR_STD_PTEX_UV:
        return "ptex_uv";               //no output
    case ATTR_STD_VOLUME_DENSITY:
        return "density";
    case ATTR_STD_VOLUME_COLOR:
        return "color";
    case ATTR_STD_VOLUME_FLAME:
        return "flame";
    case ATTR_STD_VOLUME_HEAT:
        return "heat";                  //no output
    case ATTR_STD_VOLUME_TEMPERATURE:
        return "temperature";
    case ATTR_STD_VOLUME_VELOCITY:
        return "velocity";              //no output
    case ATTR_STD_POINTINESS:
        return "pointiness";
    case ATTR_STD_RANDOM_PER_ISLAND:
        return "random_per_island";
    case ATTR_STD_NOT_FOUND:
    case ATTR_STD_NONE:
    case ATTR_STD_NUM:
        return "";
}
```

Note that for the *most part* the attribute node seems to be used as a sort of "testing node" for inputs which aren't yet available in other nodes<sup>[citation needed]</sup>. I suspect old attribute names are not removed when they do get added to another node (e.g. pointiness) as this would break backwards compatibility.

At any rate, this would at least begin to explain why there is [little to no documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html#attribute-node) about this node.

Comment: Where did you get those?.  How can I see the list in blender? or see the attributes available?. I asked here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31549/fire-and-smoke-attributes

Comment: These are the ones which listed in multiple places on the old wiki. Currently it seems like a rather arbitrary hardcoded list of things, not all of which are working yet. It seems like the attribute node is being used as sort of a "temporary input node" is used for testing newer/experimental features (e.g. a more dedicated feature rich [voxel texture node](https://developer.blender.org/T41179) is planned at some point). I did find quite a few more in the code however, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Being in some official documentation would be great :)

Comment: @darkgaze I've almost finished re-writing the smoke docs, perhaps I'll add the attribute node next ;)

Comment: I love open software... waiting for it !

Comment: Related: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/More_Features#OpenVDB_caching

Comment: this answer should be updated with heat and velocity keywords ^^