# How can vertex paint be rendered?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, vertex-colors

[image]I have added some vertex paint and would like to see it in the render.

It looks simple enough on all the tutorials, except I don't have those options available; Having spent hours researching I am still lost, how can this be done?

[image: All Material options expanded]

Comment: This is my 1st project so I am not sure what you are asking?
I have got quite far using tutorials but now I do not have the same options for enabling the vertex paint as the tutorial.

Comment: I set to cycles render on one of the 1st tutorials AJWood

Comment: I would send a full screen grab if there was an option?
I may have to edit the question to add an image?
I promise it's been set to cycles render throughout.
Can you talk me through what I need to change here

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question with a full screenshot. Perhaps also save and post the resulting .blend file

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14262/599

Comment: Ajwood summed it up well, but I personally recommend forgoing vertex paint all together and using uv texture painting. It's fast and has a better resolution. Press "u", unwrap light pack, add image in image editor, and go into texture painting mode in the 3d view.

Comment: @Caleb, yeah.. I find it tough to know whether to _answer to question_ or _tell them they asked wrong question_. Maybe address the question in one answer, and put the "what you actually should be doing is..." in a separate answer? I bet there is a SE-meta question which addresses that..

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should plug your vertex colors into the color input of your shader.

1. With your object selected, add a new material:

[image]

2. Create a meaningful name for the new material. Next, open a node editor window. One way to do this is to create a new UI window by dragging up the triangle in the bottom-left of an existing widow:

[image]

You can change the type of your new window with the button on the bottom-left -- select "Node Editor"

[image]

3. You have to type the *name* of your vertex color layer into the Attribute node. The default name is *Col*:

[image]

You can check the name of vertex color layer in the *Vertex Color* section of the *Object Data* tab in the *Properties* panel:

[image]

Comment: Got it now AJ - bless you :)

Comment: @Mikolajki If this post helped you, mark it as accepted (The check mark below the voting buttons on the right).

Comment: The check mark was on the left GianCowFilms so you lost me for a moment & I thought I was going to have to ask & appear even more foolish :/

Comment: This answer could use some more detail -- I don't even know how you got to that screen.

Comment: I think it can just be Attribute Node -> Diffuse Node -> Material Output Node