# Controlling Node Based Displacement

Tags: node-editor, vertex-groups, vertex-colors, displacement

Hey I'm making a model that uses the experimental microdisplacement to make bumps on my mesh, but I only want the bumps to be in certain parts of the mesh. Is there some way to use vertex groups or something to control where the displacement occurs?

FYI I'm using a modified voronoi texture which (as far as I know) can't be used in a displacement modifier

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use vertex colors for masking? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/how-can-vertex-paint-be-rendered

Comment: Yep, I plugged the factor of the Vertex Color into a the bottom of a multiply node I used to control the strength of Displacement and it worked! Thanks a bunch :)