# Fire and Smoke Attributes

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Where do I find the attributes available for the fire rendering at Cycles (flame, color, density...). Where is the list? or at least, how do I find which ones are available? They are not listed in the custom variables (says it's blender's programming api? are they hidden?).

Everybody talks about them but I'm not able to find them, even on the official guide at blender.org. In fact, the help pages are outdated and contain nothing about the fire and smoke and fire modes for smoke dynamics and the parameters.

This question is, in fact, a general question:
Where do I find the attributes available?.

For reference: 
http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/flow_object.html
There you can see it is always referencing a particle system. But in the volumes you have the smoke and fire AND fire options. Why doesn't it talk about it?

I'm using blender 2.74

Comment: see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/what-can-you-call-from-the-attribute-node

Comment: Nope, Chebhou. I saw it already. But gandalf3 says it. But i don't want him to tell me. I want an official guide or at least a place I can see the attributes available. My question talks about it. I want to know why, and where.

Comment: I understand, there should be something official ( i had a link to old doc but it keeps redirecting to the new empty one ) it is for getattribute()

Comment: There must be official documentation about this. There are some parameters i just don't understand. For example, flame Rate in flows.

Comment: @darkgaze AFAIK there isn't, at least beyond the few out of date mentions on the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles#Fire_and_Smoke_Rendering) and [manual](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/input.html#attribute). The *flame rate* is a simulation setting, and has nothing to do with rendering/cycles..?

Comment: As to the manual page linked in your question, the manual was just imported from the old mess of a wiki, and there are a lot of outdated pages on it. That appears to be one of them, likely part of a wiki page last updated [before 2.65](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.65/Smoke_Simulation) :/ We need all the help we can get to fix the manual up ;) Note that those simulation settings are entirely unrelated from the attribute node.

Comment: Oh. Great. :-) So... can we do something?. Being a wiki helps a lot. But as you said, it is imported... so what should we expect from now on? where should i go?. Thanks!

Comment: @darkgaze I've *finally* gotten around to updating [that bit of the manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/flow_object.html#initial-values), so it should be clearer now (I hope.. :P). If by some chance you'd like to help out with the manual project, see this [meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/855/599).

Comment: Might be worth a Try: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/More_Features#OpenVDB_caching

Answer (score 2):

You can find that Attributes on the official Page for the Attribute Node:
[Attribute Node - Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/attribute.html)

Or on the Stack Exchange Thread: [All Possible Attributes - Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/what-can-you-call-from-the-attribute-node#14267)