# Need help with making fire

Tags: physics

currently I'm making a scene, where I want a torch to have fire, I watched a few tutorials, I made a fire by pressing spacebar --> quick smoke, then I clicked on fire and got a fire animation, is there anyway to make this in render view? It's not an animation by the way, tell me if you need a .blend

[image]

Comment: You mean to render the fire?

Comment: Yep, with the f12 button you know?

Comment: did you press alt + A (in the 3d view window) to start the smoke animation?

Comment: Which render engine do you use? Blender Internal or Cycles? Provide .blend file if you can to: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Cycles, posting blend file now

Comment: Smoke is rendering actually but it is almost transparent....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you do not have the flame attributes node hooked up to your node set up.

1. In the material, add an attribute node and type **flame** into the text field
2. hook up the **fac** output to a color ramp
3. add an emissions node and set its out put to the volume in the material output node
4. Connect the color ramp to the strength input on the emission node

Answer (score 0):

So you need to adjust this value to make the smoke more dense (see the image below):
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to add the fire too?

Comment: Yes basically you should add a new attribute to the domain material called fire or flame (im not sure), check this tutorial its good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI

Comment: Also check this : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/what-can-you-call-from-the-attribute-node