# How do I set a vertex color material in Blender 2.8?

Tags: materials, vertex-colors

I have a model with vertex colors in it. I would like to display it in rendered shading. There is no more an input called vertex color.

I'm using Blender -2.80-387c1f2e0d5d-linux-glibc224-x86_64

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is Attribute node with Color output and Col parameter according your Vertex Color name.

[image: Attribute node]

**Updated:**

List of all [what can you call from the attribute node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/what-can-you-call-from-the-attribute-node)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: And what it may mean? How can I make some parts red, some parts blue? I added this attribute as base color of model shader, and became gray.

Comment: @Tertium https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDWSkCDIu1E