# how do I add vertex paint over a base material?

Tags: materials, vertex-colors

I have a model with a green base material, and I want to add vertex paint, but I don't know how to add the vertex paint in a way that doesn't fill the rest of the model with white.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a vertex color material in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140827/how-do-i-set-a-vertex-color-material-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: not really... I know how to add the nodes and stuff so that it's just vertex colours on the whole mesh, but I need to know how to add the vertex colours to part of the mesh, and the rest have a base material / colour.