# Vertex Paint not painting the areas selected on Blender2.8

Tags: vertex-paint

So I'm literally using blender 2.8 for the first time and I'm following a tutorial to make a low-poly island. I'm at where I want to paint the tip of my mountains white (while preserving the low-poly effect), what I'm doing is I selected the faces I want to paint in the Edit Mode using circle select, then I switched to Vertex Paint and picked the color using the color bar at the bottom next to "color". Then I clicked paint->set vertex colors, but it did nothing.

I'm not sure if I did something wrong or it's got something to do with blender 2.8, if anyone could point out my error or provide an alternative to my purpose it would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has an answer here.

[Is it possible to paint only on selected vertices in vertex paint?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31160/is-it-possible-to-paint-only-on-selected-vertices-in-vertex-paint)

Though I would like to add that if you are in any viewport shading mode other than *Solid*, the results won't show up in the 3D viewport when you are painting in vertex paint mode.

Also of note that after you get this working, you're very likely going to want to perform a render at some point. And you may run into more trouble when you get to that point, because vertex paint doesn't seem to want to render unless you go into the *Shader Editor* and hook up some nodes. If you later find that this is a problem, consider reviewing the following:

[How can vertex paint be rendered?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19459/how-can-vertex-paint-be-rendered)

[How do I set a vertex color material in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140827/how-do-i-set-a-vertex-color-material-in-blender-2-8)