# Mapping coordinates not working in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vector-mapping, screw-modifier

everyone! First post.

I have this very simple material node setup which both displays in Viewport Shading mode and renders in Eevee perfectly fine with no problem. In Cycles, however, all I get is a black silhouette.

The culprit appears to be the **Attribute** node at the end, which is feeding the **Vector** property into a simple **Checker Texture**. I kept the scene minimal so that the screenshots plainly lay out everything happening in both the Shader Editor and the Outliner (i.e., hardly anything) for you to see.

I need this mapping setup in order to dynamically texture a revolve/lathe surface built with the Screw modifier applied to a curve, as shown in the top screenshot pair.

For simplicity, however, further down below, I've included another pair of screenshots that illustrate the same issue using the default Torus primitive.

[image: Mapping applied to a Screw surface rendered in Eevee (top) and Cycles (bottom)]
[image: Mapping applied to a default Torus primitive rendered in Eevee (top) and Cycles (bottom)]

Comment: As a side note, your `Material Output` node has only _Eevee_ set, but that seems not to be the root cause.

Comment: @taiyo I believe that is precisely the problem.

Comment: @gcs_dev Unfortunately not. The node's target set to _Eevee_ only hides the real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your material *mat* the target option of the `Material Output` node is set to *Eevee* thus the Cycles rendering appears black. So first set it to *Cycles* or *All*. But this just hides the real problem, because then only *Color2* of the `Checker Texture` node is rendered. You need to add the name of the attribute you want to access, for a nice list see the answer in this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/what-can-you-call-from-the-attribute-node). If you write `uv` into the name field, it will work for Cycles but unfortunately not anymore for Eevee. But if you create a UV map and write that name into the name field, it works for both renderers.

[image]

Comment: Great catch on my oversight there in the Output compatibility drop-down, guys.
Thanks so much, @taiyo for the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Material Output node is set to Eevee so will display black in Cycles. Switch it to either Cycles or All.

Comment: This does not work, try the setup. Even with the `Material Output` target set to _All_ it will only output _Color2_ of the checker texture.