# How to place a texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I was continuing further on the project while I assigned different materials to the face of the cube i was stuck on assigning the the texture to highlighted face how do i do it?

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/how-do-you-apply-a-texture-to-select-faces-of-a-mesh, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/how-do-i-add-material-textures-to-only-one-face-of-an-object, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple. Start off by taking a look at the below screenshot:

[image]

1. Add a mix node and two diffuse node.
2. Put your texture (MUST have a transparent background) into one of the diffuse nodes and plug both into the mix node. (Don't mind my texture, it was the first one I found with a transparent background)
3. Make sure the diffuse node with your texture is at the bottom, you'll see why if you don't.

Thats really all there is to it. If you want to do the same thing on glass just replace the diffuse node *without* the texture with a glass node. Hope this helps!

If you want to have a glossy material on both the text and the background part you can't just use a glossy material, you will need to go a little bit deeper to get a realistic material. Have a look at this setup (to see it in full size just click the image, or right click it and choose open in new tab):

[image]

Comment: What do I do if I want to add different gloss  to both the text and background?

Comment: Just replace the diffuse node with a mix shader of a diffuse and glossy, I'll add a picture soon if you like.