# wrong image texture keeps being applied

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-painting

[image: screen shot texturing]

I am texturing using two different images.  The first one for the cats head worked fine but when I come to use a new image for the cat's body, blender keeps using the first image. See below.  On the left the eyes from the first image appear on the side of the body. can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: You need to give the object two different materials with the different textures.  The textured view mode doesn't display the material texturing, just the active texture (whichever texture is shown in the UV/image editor).

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise  It's totally possible, just give the two areas different materials.  I don't see anything wrong with using different texture files.

Comment: What? Using multiple separate image textures in a single material is done all the time! You just need to be sure to define the right UV maps for the right images on your material. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2176/599