# Map multiple textures to a face individually

Tags: texturing, uv

I have two textures mapped to a uv unwrapped face but one of them is the wrong scale. If I change the uv map to make it right it throws off the other texture. Is there any way I can have multiple uv maps for the same face so I can scale one texture without changing the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can manage them in *Object Data > UV maps*:

[image]

To use a particular map, you can select it [via the UV map node (cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2176/599):

[image]

Or in the texture settings (BI):

[image]

Comment: Arrgh . . . you beat me :P

Comment: Use the node . . .

Answer (score 4):

You can access your different UV maps while unwrapping in the *UV Image Editor*:

[image: Change UV map]

That way you can unwrap the first one, finish, and then unwrap the second one differently. Access them in the material as shown in Gandalf3's answer.