# UVMap input for nodes

Tags: uv, node-editor

I was following this tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyS8eiq14G8 and I am stuck. I don't know why I cant find the UV map input in the nodes at 15:57 if that video is my blender. Problem I am facing is that I can't find the UV mapping option when I go to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Input* in the node editor.
I am using linux 14.04 with blender version 2.69.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/can-cycles-use-multiple-uv-layers. I think you won't find *UV Map* node in 2.69; you can use *Attribute* node if not upgrading Blender.

Answer (score 3):

What he did was <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>*>[Input>UV Map](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/uv_map.html#uv-map-node)* and place this node into the [*Image Texture node*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html#image-texture-node) as shown below:

[image]

Note that the version used in the linked video is 2.71, I don't know if this was a node added after 2.69, so it may not hurt to grab a more current release (2.77a) from [Blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/)

---

As an alternative to this node however, adding an [*Input>texture coordinate* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#texture-coordinate-node), and using the [*UV Output*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html#outputs) should work just as well if this node is indeed unavailable in your  version.