# How to Combine Textures in Cycles that have been Projected from Different angles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

I'm looking for the texturing method in Cycles, similar to the texturing [method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=21&v=7679nlyZrK0) in Blender Internal Render. So i have two questions about this process:

1)How do I combine textures in Cycles that have been *Project from View*-ed from different angles? 
2)Is it possible to "draw" the overlap area of the the textures through the Texture Paint in Cycles? How to draw an alpha-channel for the textures or how to clone one texture over the other in Cycles?

Comment: Wouldn't it be exactly the same in Cycles? UV mapping and texture painting are almost exactly the same with Cycles. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @Matt I almost did not work with the Internal Render, as I understand, it has no nodes. After viewing the tutorial, I tried to repeat it in Cycles, but I realized that I don't know, how to connect several textures, (with different UV-s as input) to the same object.

Comment: Oh! I understand your problem now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Cycles use multiple UV layers?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/can-cycles-use-multiple-uv-layers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to figure out how to use different UV maps in Cycles. This question has already been answered very well [over here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/can-cycles-use-multiple-uv-layers). But I'll try to give you the basics, here.

In BI, using multiple UV maps is pretty easy. In Cycles, it's also easy but not very clear. All you have to do is give names to the multiple UV maps that you make (or use the defaults), and then reference them with an Attribute node. So, add an Attribute node in Cycles, and in the text field just type the name of the UV map you want to use, and connect the noodle from the "Vector" output, to whatever other node needs the UVs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for! :) But this is part of the question. Could you please also help me to understand how to "draw" the overlap area of the the textures through the Texture Paint in Cycles? How to draw an alpha-channel for the textures or how to clone one texture over the other in Blender?   
I'm looking for the texturing method in Cycles, similar to the texturing method in the Blender Internal Render (video tutorial above), so I combined these two questions together. If you think I'm wrong, I'll ask a second question as a new one. Thank you ones again!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that part :-/ It would be better to ask another question for that part, though. We're glad to have you on StackExchange!

Comment: Thank you, Matt! :) I'm happy to be here, I was very lucky to find a site with such a friendly and interesting creative team! :)