# Is it possible to set different textures and/or UV maps for the same mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I'm part of a small programming company, and we're designing assets for our first game. My assignment at the moment is to texture this mesh:

[image: Arcade Machine mesh]

I had to look up a few tutorials on how to do this as I'm still fairly new to Blender(as well as game design), but after a few hours, I managed to construct a decent UV Map.

[image: Arcade Machine UV map]

Now, here's where I start to run into a problem. Most of the mesh is separated into different islands, but once I start to do some texture painting, I select the faces I want to color using the bucket tool, and somehow the colors overlap onto other islands.

[[image: Overlapping colors3]

I'm thinking this has something to do with the fact that each island in the UV Editor is relatively close to one another(and also that I have the bleed factor set to 5 pixels), but it also raised a question: is it possible to assign multiple textures to the same mesh, and if so, do I have to make separate UV maps for each texture?

Basically, what I want to do here is create separate texture images for different parts of the same mesh. Like for example, I need one image for the walls of the arcade machine, and then another for the joystick and buttons.

I apologize if this has been asked before. I searched the web for an answer, but I couldn't find a solution that fit my needs.

Comment: you can assign several materials to the same object (you need to select the face to which you want to assign the material and click on the Assign button under the material list), and you can use several UV maps, one for each material (even several for the same material if you want), you have a UV map list in the Properties panel > Object Data

Comment: @moonboots I understand how to use materials, but that's not what I'm going for here. Basically, I made a single texture for the entire mesh(it's not connected to a material yet, I'm planning on doing that later), and now I just wanna know if I can create another texture image for the same mesh.

Comment: yes you could use several image textures within the same material, in that case use several UV map of the same mesh, but you could easily fix your problem with a larger margin or just make sure you only paint on the part you want with the Paint Mask option in the 3D view

Comment: Are you looking to layer multiple textures onto the one mesh, using different UV maps?

Comment: @PlanetAlexanderProjects Yeah, that's exactly what i need.

Comment: Read: [Can Cycles use Multiple UV layers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/can-cycles-use-multiple-uv-layers)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can layer multiple textures with multiple UV maps on a single object. Here I have a project from last year in which I did so. For this example, we'll look at the stitches ontop of the leather texture.

On the left is my default (base) UV map for the main texture. I've highlighted the strip where the stitches go so you can see how it changes on the next UV map.

[image]

To create a new UV map, simply click the "+" in the UV Maps section in the Object Data Properties Panel. Here is the second UV map for the stitches. As you can see I've straightened the UV islands. I've also shrunk down the rest of the UV's I don't need so they are out of the way (that's the black spot on the bottom right corner).

[image]

Once you have got these two UV maps, you'll need to load the node editor to combine the two. Here is my setup to combine the stitches and the leather:

[image]

You'll start with your Principled BSDF and Material Outpode node. Drag in the two image textures you plan to use and connect them to a MixRGB node (displayed as just Mix) as shown. Connect the Mix node to the Base Colour input on your Principled BSDF node. Finally, create an UV Map node, and edit its value to be the name of the UV map you want to *layer* on (not your base UV). Connect the UV output to the Vector input of the image to layer on.

I believe for the texture you layer on, you'll need to save it as a .png with everywhere except your texture being transparent.

Comment: Do I have to make a UV map for the entire mesh first?

Comment: Yes, this will only work if you UV unwrap it. You'll have to do it at least twice, for the base texture and any additional layers.